# I2D vs STRING for protein-protein interactions

Tags: bioinformatics, protein-interaction

Can someone clearly explain me the differences between STRING and I2D(Interlogous interaction database) ? What does each database do best ? Which database is better for what kinds of studies etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked and it seems I2D use the PPI from 5 organisms to predict interactions in those organisms, which have not yet been experimentally demonstrated, so its interolog PPI prediction tool by design (http://genomebiology.com/content/pdf/gb-2007-8-5-r95.pdf), where as STRING can be used to see what proteins are known to interact with a given protein, and what evidence is present for a particular interaction, which you then get a (confidence like) score.

Comment: So I2d is STRING + some interologous interactions without any scoring parameter. Anything wrong in what I just said

Comment: Yes, that's essentially correct although STRING is a lot more comprehensive in terms of the number of species it has PPI data for.